# How to use matplotlib's colormaps in GUI?

Tags: user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

I am making a program to simulate heat flow through nodes with a GUI in tkinter and I wanted to use matplotlib's coolwarm colormap to represent temperature. How can I take a hexadecimal value from the colormap to a variable and use it later?

Comment: How is this related to a GUI and tkinter? I would suggest to either make that clearer or to remove the respective notions from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtaining a color from a colormap is done by calling the colormap with the respective value between 0 and 1. If the colormap shall represent some data, there usually is a Normalization somewhere, `matplotlib.colors.Normalize`, which can be used to obtain the normalized value from the data.
Finally, `matplotlib.colors.to_hex` returns a color in hexadecimal format.

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors 

cmap = cm.coolwarm
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=-20, vmax=10)
variable = matplotlib.colors.to_hex(cmap(norm(5))) 
print variable
```